# preg_match pattern search when found only forward slash or backward slash

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Currently I'm having problems when searching `/` and `\` using `preg_match`

First:
I want my condition true only when the `$searchWord` contains only `/` or `\`.

```
$searchWord = preg_match('/[\/~`\\\]/', $searchWord) ? '*' : $searchWord;
```

Second:
If any word contains `/`

```
example: $searchWord='event/'
```

then

```
$searchWord='event' . suffix '*'
```

Comment: What's the purpose of preg_match here? Would this be suitable? $searchWord = ($searchWord == '/' || $searchWord == '\\') ? '*' : $searchWord;

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. I usually love using preg_match, but in this case a couple of substr() comparisons may be easier.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answering ! But if the case 'event/' then will become 'event*' I want to concat with suffix

Comment: that the pattern will scan if any words contain with '/'

Comment: Please revise the question. I don't understand what your trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MarkChhunlong Can you explain more about what you want with the suffix using code examples?

Comment: @jjwdesign I'm trying to adjust my question I hope you can understand ! Really thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to well understand your needs, but is this what you want:

```
$searchWord = preg_replace('#[/~`\\\]#', '*', $searchWord);
```

Comment: Thanks @Toto for answered ! but for # what does it mean ? Any characters ?

Comment: @MarkChhunlong: In this case, `#` is the delimiter of the regex, it allows to not have to escape the slash.